# ARCGIS feature layer extract all records

Tags: python, python-requests, arcgis, arcpy

I am querying ARCGIS feature service URL using requests library. when querying the data i got only 2000 records but my arcgis rest api contains 90000 records. How to extract all the records in the arcgis feature layer. I have used the following code.

```
import requests
params = {
    "token": token,
    "f": "json",  
    "where": "1=1",
    "returnGeometry": "false",
    "outFields": "*",
    "returnCountOnly":"true",
    "outSR": 4326
    }
url = FEATURE_LAYER_URL
feature_layer_responce = requests.post(url, params=params)
feature_layer_responce.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ArcGIS feature service limits the number of records for each request. You would need to change the `maxRecordCount` value for the REST endpoint:

- [How To: Update the maximum record count for feature services in ArcGIS Online](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012383)

---

In case if you only need the IDs:

> While there is a limit to the number of features included in the response (see the `maxRecordCount` property of the feature service), there is no limit to the number of object IDs returned in the ID array response. Clients can exploit this to get all the query conforming object IDs by specifying `returnIdsOnly=true` and subsequently requesting feature sets for subsets of object IDs.

- [Query (Feature Service)](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/query-feature-service-.htm)